# Syntax for using XPATH and Sendkeys in case of DeprecatedWarnings using Latest Selenium version

Tags: python, selenium, syntax-error, attributeerror

I am trying to find email and password fields by XPATH and trying to send keys as well but I am getting the error, need syntax of finding element by XPATH while using latest selenium version and getting DeprecationWarning:

[image]

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tInf0.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `findElement` method in `Python-Selenium` bindings. Note that `findElement` is available in `Java-Selenium` bindings.

for Python you should use:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "XPath here").send_keys('keys to be sent here')
```

this should help you resolve syntax error.

Your final code block should look like this:

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='email']").send_keys('AA01@hotmail.com')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='pass']").send_keys('password here')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@name='login']").click()
```

You can replace these `find_element` with the explicit wait as well like below:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='email']"))).send_keys('AA01@hotmail.com')
```

for this you will have to **import**:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```